# ler arquivo txt com menos de 5 elementos usando read.table

Tags: r, txt

Estou tentando ler o arquivo txt com duas colunas abaixo:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                      Category Information                        |    square|
| #|description                                                    |     miles|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 3| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  2.096540|
| 4| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . | 14.719017|
|15| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  4.763791|
|19| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  0.002395|
|21| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  2.780825|
|25| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  0.087930|
|33| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  0.484098|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|TOTAL                                                             | 24.934597|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Estou usando a seguinte linha de código:

```
rawdata<-read.table("1986.txt", sep = "|",skip = 5)
```

Mas ele não lê nada e retorna que não há o mínimo de 5 elementos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reproduzindo o problema:

```
tf <- tempfile()
write.table(
  "+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                      Category Information                        |    square|
   | #|description                                                    |     miles|
   |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
   | 3| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  2.096540|
   | 4| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . | 14.719017|
   |15| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  4.763791|
   |19| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  0.002395|
   |21| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  2.780825|
   |25| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  0.087930|
   |33| . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  0.484098|
   |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
   |TOTAL                                                             | 24.934597|
   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+",
   tf, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)

rawdata <- read.table(tf, sep = "|", skip = 5)
```

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>     line 7 did not have 5 elements

O arquivo tem alguns problemas.

1. Há linhas que não contem informação tabular (`|---...---`). 
   Quando o [r](/questions/tagged/r) encontra essa linha, ele não encontra ali as mesmas 5 colunas que estava encontrando nas linhas anteriores e joga o erro.
2. Presençado caracter `"#"`: ele é lido por padrão como um comentário na `read.table()`.
3. A última linha, com o total, não respeita o padrão do resto do arquivo (não tem `|` após "TOTAL"

Além disso os `|` inicial e final não adicionam nenhum informação a tabela e geram duas colunas inúteis quando os dados forem lidos

Para resolver a leitura desses dados vejo ao menos dois caminhos possíveis.

### r-base

Um caminho é ler o dado com `readLines()`, retirar essas linhas incomodas e depois passar os dados "limpos" para a `read.table()`

```
txt <- readLines(tf)
limpo <- txt[! grepl("----|TOTAL", txt)]
rawdata <- read.table(text = limpo, sep = "|", skip = 1, comment.char = "")
rawdata

  V1 V2                                                              V3         V4 V5
1 NA  # description                                                          miles NA
2 NA  3  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    2.096540 NA
3 NA  4  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   14.719017 NA
4 NA 15  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    4.763791 NA
5 NA 19  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    0.002395 NA
6 NA 21  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    2.780825 NA
7 NA 25  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    0.087930 NA
8 NA 33  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    0.484098 NA
```

### tidyverse

No [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) o pacote para ler arquivos é o [readr](/questions/tagged/readr). Usando ele teríamos:

```
library(tidyverse)
rawdata2 <- read_delim(tf, "|", skip = 2, comment = "----")
rawdata2 %>% filter(!is.na(` #`))

# A tibble: 8 x 5
  `   ` ` #`                        `description                   ~ `     miles` X5   
  <chr> <chr>                       <chr>                            <chr>        <chr>
1 "   " " 3"                        " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .~ "  2.096540" NA   
2 "   " " 4"                        " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .~ " 14.719017" NA   
3 "   " 15                          " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .~ "  4.763791" NA   
4 "   " 19                          " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .~ "  0.002395" NA   
5 "   " 21                          " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .~ "  2.780825" NA   
6 "   " 25                          " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .~ "  0.087930" NA   
7 "   " 33                          " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .~ "  0.484098" NA   
8 "   " "TOTAL                    ~ " 24.934597"                     NA           NA
```

Observe que nos dois casos as tabelas não são iguais, porque no segundo caso a linha com total pode ser mantida.

Answer (score 4):

Sabendo o que está no ficheiro, o seguinte funciona. Não é é absolutamente nada geral.

```
dados <- read.table(file = "Artur.txt", 
                    sep = "|", comment.char = "+", 
                    skip = 4, fill = TRUE)

dados <- dados[!sapply(dados, function(x) all(is.na(x)))]
dados <- dados[apply(dados, 1, function(x) !any(grepl("----", x))), ]
dados$V4[nrow(dados)] <- as.numeric(as.character(dados$V3[nrow(dados)]))
dados <- dados[-2]
dados$V2 <- droplevels(dados$V2)
dados$V2 <- trimws(as.character(dados$V2))
names(dados) <- c("number", "sq.miles")

dados
#  number  sq.miles
#1      3  2.096540
#2      4 14.719017
#3     15  4.763791
#4     19  0.002395
#5     21  2.780825
#6     25  0.087930
#7     33  0.484098
#9  TOTAL 24.934597
```